# Задать название термина "Длина интервала времени"

Tags: терминология

Вопрос частично программистский: есть интервал времени.
Начало интервала времени задается в программе в полуавтоматическом режиме.

А вот конец интервала - задается пользователем.

Например: 1-й интервал 00:00:00 и до 00:00:10. То есть "длина интервала" равна 10 секундам.

Есть ли более подходящее название для "длины интервала"? Период?

Comment: Продолжительность?

Comment: Время работы, время выполнения. Ну и "продолжительность", как написал @VladD

Comment: Тут фишка в том, что при каждом запуске- начало интервала будет смещаться во времени. Ну и конец интервала-тоже. Это не продолжительность... Может период?

Comment: длительность подойдет?